# Postgres a timestamp column constraint from NOT NULL to NULL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints, create-table

I'm trying to run a migration and make basically a column "modified" which is NOT NULL to be NULL. Like there is no need to have that constraint on it, I've run yoyo migrations and have the following output

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "timestamp"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE shop ALTER COLUMN modified timestamp NULL
```

Pointing to the timestamp ^

the table itself looks

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    uuid uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    modified timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    deleted timestamp with time zone
);
```

I've tried to search the web, and found a few similar articles on stackoverflow but it didn't help, so hopefully someone here can help.

Edit:

```
steps = [
    step("""ALTER TABLE phrases 
    ALTER COLUMN modified TYPE timestamp,
    ALTER column modified SET NULL
;""")
]
```

In yoyo migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can make a column nullable with `DROP NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE shop ALTER column modified DROP NOT NULL;
```

If you want to change the datatype at the same time, then:

```
ALTER TABLE shop 
    ALTER column modified DROP NOT NULL,
    ALTER COLUMN modified TYPE timestamp
;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4d5ca9d2382956b80ae0905b0215166c)**

Comment: and for the roleback would i do something like
```ALTER TABLE shop ALTER column modified SET NOT NULL;```?

Comment: @Stas: yes, that's how you do it.